# linear wipe text effect using CSS or CSS3 animate

Tags: javascript, css

How to show text reveal with " linear wipe " effect using CSS and JavaScript. How to do that?

```
<p>Text linear wipe </p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "linear wipe"? Display one character at a time until all characters are displayed?

Comment: yes that is Linear Wipe actually :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this snippet:

```css
p{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30em;
  animation: linearwipe 6s steps(60, end); 
}

@keyframes linearwipe{ 
  from { width: 0; } 
}
```

```html
<p>Text linear wipe </p>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, i want the same effect but the text should not move. It should be in same place. ex. "typing text" .

Comment: exactly this is i want, can we add some opacity from 0 to 100% ?

Comment: Good luck @Sharavnan :)

Comment: one more issue, i tried with multiple lines of text, but its showing only one line. others are not visible. @Hitesh Misro

Comment: @Sharavnan You have to define another `@keyframe` check here - https://jsfiddle.net/foLf5sny/1/ or check this jQuery solution - http://jsfiddle.net/f2JpQ/

Answer (score 1):

This code is perfectly working:

CSS:

```
.linear-wipe{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden; 
  animation: linearwipe 1s steps(100, end); 
  opacity: 1;
  width: 0%;
}

@keyframes linearwipe{ 
  from { width: 0;opacity: 0 } 
}
```